# MySql Stored Procedure mangles str_to_date() function

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

***MySql Stored Procedure mangles str_to_date() function.***

***When the following MySQL query is run in the terminal mode it works fine.***

```
 UPDATE `tt002grawdata` SET `bizdate` = str_to_date(`BusinessDate`,'%m/%d/%y');

         Query OK, 75 rows affected, 2028 warnings (0.01 sec)
         Rows matched: 2028   Changed: 75   Warnings: 0
```

***However, when placed within a MySQL Stored Procedure the update query is mangled.***

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_upd
 BEGIN
 UPDATE `tt002grawdata` SET `bizdate` = str_to_date(`BusinessDate`,'%m/%d/%y');
 End $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

***Please Note str_to_date() function has changed thus gives an error.***

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
 that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'BEGIN
 UPDATE `tt002grawdata` SET `bizdate` = str_to_date(`BusinessDate`,'%m/%d/'
 at line 2
```

***Is there a work-a-round for this problem ?***

***Thanks.***

***Edward.***

Answer (score 0):

You need a `()` along with your stored procedure name. Your procedure body should look like below. Refer [MySQL Documentation On Create procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for more information.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_upd()
 BEGIN
 UPDATE `tt002grawdata` SET `bizdate` = str_to_date(`BusinessDate`,'%m/%d/%y');
 End $$
 DELIMITER ;
```